# how to use JsonDocument in Scala with Couchbase Java SDK 3.x?

Tags: scala, couchbase-java-client

I am trying to migrate from Couchbase Java-sdk 2.7.23 to 3.x. Can't resolve flatMap with the below in Scala.

Unable to resolve flatMap() while fetching multiple documents from Couchbase

```
val reactiveCollection = bucket.scope("default").collection("default").reactive()
val docsToFetch = util.Arrays.asList("doc1", "doc2").toList

val fetchedResult: List[GetResult] = Flux.fromIterable(docsToFetch)
  .flatMap(key => reactiveCollection.get(key))
  .collectList()
  .block()
```

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with the flatMap function. Only thing you need to do is convert java list to scala list as below

```
  val reactiveCollection = bucket.scope("default").collection("default").reactive
  val docsToFetch: util.List[String] = java.util.Arrays.asList("doc1", "doc2")

  import scala.collection.JavaConverters._

  val fetchedResult: List[GetResult] = Flux.fromIterable(docsToFetch)
    .flatMap { key => reactiveCollection.get(key) }
    .collectList()
    .block().asScala.toList
```

Comment: I tried to convert to scala list by adding 'asScala.toList'. But, JavaConverters remain unused and no error is thrown for "asScala.toList". My Scala version is 2.11.12, anyother suggestions?